# counting oligonucleotides and reversed complementary

Tags: r

I'm start to using R and i need some help if it's possible.  I need to read fasta files and count for each species the frequency of each nucleotide, dinucleotides and to words with length 10 and the frequency of the reversed complementary. I'm using the package Biostrings. Can you Help me?  Thank You

Comment: You should show current attempt in solving this

Answer (score 0):

The [Bioconductor Biostring Manual](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/Biostrings/man/Biostrings.pdf) contains some pretty descriptive methods that match what you are looking for.  They also have attached examples.  Otherwise, you could just read in the FASTA file and keep track of how many of each base occurs (If you can't figure out the BioString program).

For the frequency, simply [reading from a text file (FASTA after removing name sequences)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing) is also sufficient. As long as you keep count of how many of each oligonucleotide appears.

I'm not exactly sure how you want to measure how much reverse complementary there is, if you kept all the possibilities of size 10 in an array that array wouldn't be too large (4^10 I think?), so if you add the data to the array in a logical way you could pretty easily compare them in an algorithmic manner.